# Google Sheets получить индексы всех ячеек содержащих похожие значения

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть у меня таблица, в которой содержатся данные в формате:

| заголовок | заголовок | заголовок |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Омск | Москва | Питер |
| 10000 | 241432 | 124455 |
| Питер | Омск | Питер |
| 99900 | 1 | 2144 |

Я хочу получить все индексы, содержащие слово "Питер".
Ну и дальше уже их использовать в своих функциях.

Конечная задача это сумму получить всех чисел под всеми словами "Питер".

Пока что пытаюсь решить проблему без QUERY(), возможно ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(A2:C4;"Питер";A3:C5)
```

Вместо слова вписать ссылку на ячейку - можно получать суммы по любому городу, меняя значение в ячейке.

Еще унифицируем:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(A2:C4;"*"&E2&"*";A3:C5)
```

Например, в таблице есть значения "город Питер", "питерский", в Е2 пишем "итер" - будут просуммированы все значения, которые находятся под ячейками с фрагментом "итер". Если Е2 = "ск", будет получена сумма по двум городам )